# Tip the balance

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

I wanted to know that as the definition of “tip the balance” is (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tip-the-balance);
Does this statement make sense?
“Being addicted to computers cuts both ways but the example of telecommuting tips the balance in favor of advantages.”
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the sentence probably means that even though being addicted to computers has its advantages and disadvantages, telecommuting causes the advantages to outweigh the disadvantages.

So therefore "tip the balance" represents how telecommuting "adds more weight" to the advantages, so it is in favour of the advantages. The balance in this case represents how the advantages and disadvantages cancelled each other out intially.

So yes your sentence makes sense and is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, so it makes sense? Because it is my own statement

Comment: Yes people can interpret it easily so your sentence should be fine @sourenasaeedzadeh